# NSData型をNSJSONSerializationするとエラーがでてしまう。

Tags: swift, php, xcode, json

```
func sendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest) -> NSDictionary {
    var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil
    var err: NSError?

    var dataVal: NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: &err)!


    println(dataVal)

    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    return jsonResult
```

したから２行目で以下のエラーが出てしまいます。
exc_bad_instruction　（code= EXC_l386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

原因がわからないので些細なことでもわかるかたアドバイスよろしくお願い致します。